# Extract all substrings that match a pattern in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a string in a text file as below.

```
<sample:Recipients><sample:user name="11111111" guid="8fa4fbaabf904a16ad65449bd7adcba1"/><sample:user name="22222222" guid="f74ebd3310834601a2c22a5dde33c02a"/><sample:user name="33333333" guid="5fcd2e7775cb42ecbed5ac5dd85e1ca6"/></sample:Recipients>
```

The string is continuous and not formatted as proper xml

I have to extract all the values from  tags

I have used the below script

```
grep -o "<sample:Recipients>.*</sample:Recipients>" "sample.txt"|sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/p'
```

But I am getting only the last value `33333333`. How can I extract the values from all user tags?

Comment: Please mention expected output in CODE TAGS in your post it too now.

Comment: Expected output is the list of values `11111111` `22222222` `33333333`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following quick and dirty `grep` commands to reach your objective:

```
$ grep -E 'sample:Recipients>|<sample:user' file | grep -oP '(?<=name=")[^"]*'
```

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat file 
abc
abc1
<sample:Recipients>
   <sample:user name="******1" guid="8fa4fbaabf904a16ad65449bd7adcba1"/>
   <sample:user name="*******2" guid="f74ebd3310834601a2c22a5dde33c02a"/> 
   <sample:user name="*******3" guid="5fcd2e7775cb42ecbed5ac5dd85e1ca6"/> 
</sample:Recipients>
abc2
abc
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ grep -E 'sample:Recipients>|<sample:user' file | grep -oP '(?<=name=")[^"]*'
******1
*******2
*******3
```

**Explanations:**

The first `grep` will fetch the lines that contains the XML you want to isolate from your input file, the second one will select the values from the attributes called `name` by using a `perl` regex `(?<=name=")[^"]*` with positive lookbehind.

Another quick and dirty solution using `sed`:

```
$ grep -E 'sample:Recipients>|<sample:user' file | sed -n '/name="/s/.*name="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/gp'
******1
*******2
*******3
```

**Explanations:**

You use `sed` and process lines only when matching the pattern `name=` then you replace the whole line by the backreference to the name value: `\1` (the attribute value)

**THE GOOD SOLUTION:**

instead of grepping or using `sed` just use a xml parser to analyse your xml output:

```
$ cat extract_name.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declation="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/@name">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

$ xsltproc extract_name.xsl <(grep -E 'sample:Recipients>|<sample:user' file) 2>/dev/null
******1
*******2
*******3
```

This is the safest way of working, note that the `2>/dev/null` is used in order to ignore the namespace warning because the sample namespace is not properly defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tested and it works. Can we do it using sed as well?

Comment: @Allan I don't think the sed part works as OP changed the sample file format.

Comment: @JamesBrown: thanks James, indeed I will need to edit my answer, in the mean time I have added a better answer using XML parsing ;-)

Comment: dunno about xsltproc, but it xmlstarlet seems simpler...  `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//@name' ip.txt 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @Sundeep: thanks a lot! I will have a look at this command ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Following single `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/sample:user name=\"[^"]*[0-9]+/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART+18,RLENGTH-18);
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Nice `awk` answer as usual +1 ;-)

Comment: @Allan, thanks Allan, you ROCK too buddy, as always :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `awk` script":

```
awk -v RS='<[a-z:]+|/>' -v FS='[a-z]+=' '{gsub("[\" ]",""); print $2,$3}'
```

THe record separator RS is set to get everything between `<...\>`. The field separtor is set to catch the left part of the sign `=`.

The `gsub` command gets rid of double quotes and extra spaces.

The print statement is displaying the name and guid. If you don't need guid, remove `,$3` in the `print` statement.